# Squares in Algebraic Extensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, algebraic-numbers

Sorry if that's a hard question, but is there an "easy" way to determine when an element inside a (real) simple field extension of $\mathbb Q$, is a perfect square ? (The one in question is a 3rd degree non-integral extension, and the elements have $\mathbb Z$-coefficients, maybe that helps a little). I'm not interested that much in calculating the square root effectively, if it exists inside the extension, though that would help.

Comment: Please give the concrete example you have in mind

Comment: The field is $\mathbb Q(r)$ where $r$ is a root of $4x^3-87x^2+120x+755$, the element in question is $q=16r^2+100r+145=1+(2r+8)(8r+18)$, which I went ahead and did some calculations and is actually integral with equation $q^3-9219q^2+7192755q-7535025=0$